# how to make "docker build" starts from the point it was last failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am trying to create a run the following command:

```
docker build .
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
# gets the docker image of ruby 2.5 and lets us build on top of that
FROM ruby:2.3.1-slim

RUN uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --machine
RUN cat /etc/os-release

# W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: AA8E81B4331F7F50
# RUN apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring
# RUN apt-key update
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50

# install rails dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev git-core zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev curl

RUN echo "Curl version:"
RUN curl --version

RUN curl -o- -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -

# Install Yarn from script
RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -
RUN echo "Yarn install version"
RUN yarn --version

# RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553

# create a folder /myapp in the docker container and go into that folder
RUN mkdir /avocado
WORKDIR /avocado

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from app root directory into the /avocado/ folder in the docker container
COPY Gemfile /avocado/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /avocado/Gemfile.lock

# Run bundle install to install gems inside the gemfile
RUN bundle install

# Copy the whole app
COPY . /avocado
```

docker script failed for example in line:

```
RUN curl -o- -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
```

because of some reasons and then changed the script and run **docker build .** again, however Docker start from the beginning. This is very inconvenient and time consuming for me. To reach to the point it was failed I have to wait for almost 4Gbb of storage space to be redone and taking approx 10mn before I know my change work or not.

It would be good If It could just continue running from where it failed for example for this line onward

```
RUN curl -o- -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
```

I am wondering how to achieve this? or you have any better approach to overcome this issue?

Comment: no it will not start from the beginning unless you use `--no-cache`. the build will use cached steps

Comment: You could create an image with the previous correctly build steps and move the rest steps to a new Dockerfile that is build from the first image.
Once the second image is build, any changes done, have cached steps, so will not start from the begining of the second Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker build keeps cached of only those layer which successfully builds and start from the next layer that is failed unless you explicitly pass `--no-cache` as mentioned by @linpy. So in your case

```
# Install Yarn from script
RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -
RUN echo "Yarn install version"
RUN yarn --version
.
.
.
```

In the above case if it failed at curl so it will start in next build from curl and then will build the rest of the layer.

**Workaround:**

- Move these line to the end of the docker if next layer not depended on this.

```
RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -
```

Comment: Each time it failed it created a new image too. I think creating image each time is time consuming too. This is why I have to wait for 4Gb to be copied

Comment: think of intermediate layer as an image but you can remove them too. `--rm=true                       Remove intermediate containers after a successful build` or `--force-rm=true, those intermediate containers would always been removed even in case of an unsuccessful compilation.`